# How to get data from nested collection in Flutter firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, provider

I am using `provider` and `Stream` to fetch  data from Firestore. so now i want to access the inner collection. but i am not able to fetch the data. How can i access  myOrders collection.
 this is the structure of firestore. [image]

[image]

i tried this code to fetch but not worked for me.

````
//Store data into myOrders collection

  Future myOrders(String image, String price) async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    return await userData
        .document(user.uid)
        .collection('myOrders')
        .document()
        .setData({
      'orderedImage': image,
      'orderedPrice': price,
    });
  }
    // get the data as snapshot

  List<OrderedModel> myOrderSnapShot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return OrderedModel(
          orderedImage: doc.data['orderedImage'] ?? '',
          orderedPrice: doc.data['orderedPrice']);
    }).toList();
  }

   // get the snapshot as stream

  Stream<List<OrderedModel>> get orderedStream {
    return userData.document(uid).collection('myOrders').snapshots().map(myOrderSnapShot);
  }```
````

Comment: Can you show how do you use these methods?

Answer (score 1):

did you try printing the values and debug the code?

Comment: yeah, i was getting null value in userId, I solved it. thanks